# Solve $\sum_{t=0}^T \exp(xt) v_t = y$ for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve in closed form:

$\sum_{t=0}^T \exp(xt) v_t = y$ for $x$ given some arbitrary positive constants $y$ and $v_t$

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite $z = e^x$, your equation becomes $\sum \limits_{t = 0}^T v_t z^t -y = 0$. But this is a polynomial equation and for $T > 4$ there is no general solution in form of standard mathematical functions (and the formula for $T > 2$ is already very complicated).